# What could be the voltage of this common DC motor?

Tags: voltage, motor, dc-motor, current-measurement

Below is the picture of a common DC motor usually used in electronic toys. Because this motor is so common, does someone knowing it's voltage and how much current it draws? (I could've tested it by myself but currently don't have the testing devices.)

[image: Common DC Motor]

Comment: Did you pull it from some device? What was that device designed to feed to it?

Comment: A search on Amazon results in most of these small motors being 1.5-3 V (two AA batteries). Although, certain similar looking models can go up to 12 V.

Comment: @adamaero please don't make trivial edits to ancient, fundamentally unanswerable questions which are properly closed.  All doing such does is waste people's time.  There is simply no way that *any* 3rd party edit could fix what is wrong with this.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Whoa! People hammer on me when I tell people not to erect zombie questions. What’s the secret password?

Comment: I found it useful. Additionally, comments are not for extended discussion.

Answer (score 5):

There is absolutely no way to tell just by looking at it. You are probably safe putting 1.5V on it, maybe as much as 4-5V. But it could designed for higher voltage, or not.

If you do your homework and find **datasheets** for similar size and construction motors and gather the tools (multimeter and bench power supply) you can probably get close to figuring out (roughly) the design voltage and other specifications.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen that kind of motor when I was a teenager, many years ago, and you are quite right, it's fairly common.  It could be 12V, because I think it was used in model racing cars.
I don't think it will be any higher than this.

Anyway, best not to assume. Test it out, use a power supply for which you can change the voltage and increase the voltage slowly. The issue will be the current, if the current increases too much, the motor will burn out. From what I recall, the windings on this kind of motor are quite thin, so it won't take amps of current, you may find a few hundred milliamps up to perhaps an amp. But once it's burned out, it's burned out, so make sure it doesn't get too hot as you crank up the voltage.

Step the voltage up bit by bit, and let it run at that speed for a while, measure the current.  If it starts to get too warm then you're probably pushing too much current through it.

Motors are current driven devices, the current creates a magnetic field which then causes the motor to rotate. The speed of rotation is controlled by the current. It's hard to say exactly what the maximum amount of current it will take is.

Answer (score -4):

Maximum voltage of such a motor is 12V dc

Comment: What do you base this on? I have a handfull of motors that looke exactly like the one shows. half of them are for 3V, the others are for 5V. But I bet you could get them for 12V, maybe even for 24V.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Where did you get so much motors? Where can I buy some with so many voltage variants?

Comment: That is a rather firm blanket statement that has absolutely no basis in fact.  There are many motors that size that run at least up to 90VDC, but more commonly are under 48VDC.  There is no way to tell anything by looking at that picture except that it has two connections for power in (or out, could be a tachometer too), and a shaft for a mechanical load (or supply).

Comment: @jNerd I run a small webshop, so I sample and buy from many sources. For a start, try aliexpress and dealextreme.